# How can I convert the string value of a jQuery object into an actual jQuery object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this string in my JS code right now:

```
newWords = '$(p span.word[style="--' + paraIndex + 'word-index:undefined"], p span.whitespace[style="--' + paraIndex + 'word-index:undefined"])';
```

I want to convert this string into a jQuery object that I can use do identify those specific elements.

I also saw the eval() function. That looks like it does what I want it to, but is super unsafe/unsecure.

Does anyone know a safe way to do this?

Comment: How about removing `$(` and `)` and then simply passing the string as an argument to `$()`?

Comment: @AngelPolitis That works great! Sometimes the simplest solution does the job, thanks!

Comment: I'm glad I could help @GrahamBillington. I'll post it as an answer to provide an executable snippet for anyone with the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is to remove `$(` and `)` and pass the remaining string as an argument to `$()`:

```js
var paraIndex = 0;
var newWords = '$(p span.word[style="--' + paraIndex
  + 'word-index:undefined"], p span.whitespace[style="--'
  + paraIndex + 'word-index:undefined"])';

var jQ = $(newWords.slice(2, -1));

console.log(jQ);
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```